# How Can I Append Data After A Certain Element in a List

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of integers and want to append data after a certain element in the list. I know about the list function, but when I go to use it in a loop, it appends the same data in the same position `x` amount of times.

Here is what I have:

```
lister = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
counter = 0

for i in range (len(lister)):
    lister.insert(i, "Hello")

print(lister)
```

When I run it, I get `['Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

How would I make it so that when I run it, I get, `[Hello, 1 , Hello, 2, ...]` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small change:

```
lister.insert(i*2, "Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spend about thirty minutes trying to fix this!! Very helpful! :)

Comment: My pleasure, but look I think this prints `Hello 1 Hello 2....` rather than `1 Hello 2 Hello`. I would suggest accepting Valentin's answer.

Comment: That was a typo. The way yours works is what I wanted. I'll fix that in the original question! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your loop first runs, it inserts "Hello" as the first item, so `lister` becomes: `['Hello', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

When it runs the second time, it insert "Hello" as the second item, which is... before the "1", because you added something else in first position. So `lister` becomes: `['Hello', 'Hello', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

etc.

Instead, you must skip an item each time: when you insert the second Hello, you must insert it in third position, not second. And the third hello must be in fifth position. Then seventh, then ninth, etc.

Like this:

```
for i in range (len(lister)):
    lister.insert(i*2, "Hello")
```

And now, you get this:

```
['Hello', 1, 'Hello', 2, 'Hello', 3, 'Hello', 4, 'Hello', 5]
```

However, that's still not exactly what you want. To do what you want, you need one extra change: skip the first item, which you can do by adding in position `i*2+1` instead of `i*2`.

Comment: Ah I missed the order. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because once you insert an element in the list, the overall index of all elements in the list gets updated. So you need to account for that when inserting the new element, since old indexes do not hold anymore

```
# your code goes here
lister = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Keep a count of elements inserted till now
insert_count = 0
for i in range (1, len(lister)):
    # The new position of the element is 
    # i + the elements inserted till now
    lister.insert(i + insert_count, "Hello")
    insert_count +=1

print(lister)
# [1, 'Hello', 2, 'Hello', 3, 'Hello', 4, 'Hello', 5]
```